# Вывод текста по условию

Tags: php

Есть значения, которые мы вводим через форму и добавляем её в БД.
 Далее берем из базы значения и выводим их

```
$s=mysql_query("select * from i_block where id=".$r["id_section"]."");
        $rr=mysql_fetch_array($s);

        $ss=mysql_query("select * from i_block where id=".$rr["id_section"]."");
        $rru=mysql_fetch_array($ss);

    echo'
    <br />
<strong style="font-size:13px;">Помещение в аренде: </strong>'.($r["cat_ar"]!=0?'Да':'Нет').'<br />
```

В конечном результате нам выходит сообщение "Помещение в аренде: ДА/НЕТ.
Как сделать так, чтобы когда "да", то писалось "Помещение в аренде: ДА",
а когда "нет", то не писалось ничего. В плане данный пункт.
Прошу извинить, если неграмотно растолковал вопрос, у меня 3 часа ночи уже, спать хочу, а сделать кровь из носу надо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если я правильно понял.

```
 echo'
 <br />
 ',($r["cat_ar"]!=0?
 '<strong style="font-size:13px;">Помещение в аренде: Да</strong>':''),'<br />';
```

Comment: Я от отчаянья уже написал то, что первое в голову пришло

    if ($r["cat_ar"]==1)
    {
        echo '<strong  style="font-size:13px;"> Помещение в аренде -  ДА</strong>';
    }

Ваш вариант вполне хорош!